# Change CSS based on cursor position with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, cursor-position

I included tooltips on my website with CSS but since the site is responsive, some tooltips can be displayed off screen. So I wanted to adjust tooltip position based on the cursor position when you view the tooltip. Vertical tooltip alignment is not an issue and all tooltips are displayed to the right of the "text-to-hover" so I just want to translate the tooltip to the left when it comes too close to the right end of the screen/window.

This is the HTML:

```
<span class="tooltip-box">text-to-hover
  <span class="tooltip-text">Tooltip text here!</span>
</span>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.tooltip-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip-box .tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.tooltip-box:hover .tooltip-text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And this is the Javascript, which should determine whether to translate the tooltip horizontally by -100% if the cursor is too close to the end of the screen:

```
<script>
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var pageX = e.pageX;
}

var vert = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
if((pageX+320)>vert) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-text").css("transform", "translateX(-100%)");
}
</script>
```

I placed the JS into the footer of each page but the JS code doesn't seem to change anything. I'm relatively new to JS so I'm assuming I'm the problem. Please tell me, where I'm the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you never listen to any event to run your function. Consider this code instead.

```
<script>
var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-text")
function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var pageX = e.pageX;

    var vert = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

    if((pageX+320)>vert) {
      tooltip.css("transform", "translateX(-100%)");
    } else {
      tooltip.css("transform", "translateX(0)");
    }
}
  
tooltip.addEventListener('mouseenter', handler)
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your version with the event listener but it didn't seem to change anything. Am I supposed to add the eventListener to the tooltip or to the function?